# Telethon client login through the presence of a session file does not work on plesk scheduled task but it runs normaly via SSH

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, plesk, telethon

I have a VPS running on plesk (debian 10). I've created a python script for telegram using telethon.

I used ssh to run the script for the first time in order to input the code received on my phone so that it created a .session file and goes without the need of the code for future executions.

The script performed as expected and does not requires a code verification anymore as the .session file is present in the directory.

I tried scheduling a cron task via plesk for the script but it does not work, the script act like it requires a code, and i'm receiving a code verification on my phone, so it is manifesting as if the .session file was not there.

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
api_id = 'xxxxxx'
api_hash = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
phone = '+1xxxxxxx' #the same as session name: '+1xxxxxxxx.session'

client = TelegramClient('+15812571726', api_id, api_hash)

client.connect()

if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))

....do stuff
```

Does anyone have an idea why is this failing ? Can I load the session before calling the `client.connect()` so this way i'm sure it is loaded ?

Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is most likely a path issue.
try using an absolute path since the session file is created in the folder where the script is called.

Comment: Yes,For anyone who is having the same problem:

You should copy the .session file generated in the Home_Directory of the domain because scheduled tasks runs in your domain and it uses the home dir to use utility files.